# CakePHP 1.3 - Getting nested data from Form->input()?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, input, cakephp-1.3

I'm upgrading a system from CakePHP 1.1 to CakePHP 1.3. In 1.1 I was able to use the HTML helper to do something like:

```
$html->input('User/email');
```

To get back data nested in:

```
$this->data['User']['email']
```

In the controller. Now I know that `$html->input()` has been replaced with `$this->Form->input()`. However, when I try to use:

```
$this->Form->input('User/email')
```

I get:

```
Undefined offset: 2 [CORE\cake\libs\view\helpers\form.php, line 496]
```

This is coming up because the `/` in the input. So it seems that 1.3 doesn't like using the `/` to specify the data should be returned nested. How might I achieve the equivalent of this in 1.3? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.3 you would use

```
$this->Form->input('User.email');
```

To set an input for the User model and the email field.

If you have set up your form correctly though, you just need `email`

For example

```
$this->Form->create('User');

$this->Form->input('email');

$this->Form->end('Submit');
```

But in short, to answer your specific question, replace the / with a .